# How can I pick the data directory of Bitcoin Core on Windows 10?

Tags: bitcoin-core, windows, storage-footprint, datadir

I'm using Bitcoin Core on Windows 10.  Despite setting it up in a folder on my larger drive, it's eating all the space on my SSD. How do I direct the blockchain to the drive I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to set the option `-datadir=<path-to-your-drive>` either when starting `bitcoind`, or in your `bitcoin.conf` file. If you add it to `bitcoin.conf`, you'll need to restart your node for the change to take effect.

Comment: Rock on Chytrik, that did it.  For anyone else reading this thread later it helps to copy the data over from the Roaming\appdata\Bitcoin directory or you'll be starting all over again (relative to any progress you may have made before realizing your drive was being consumed by the blockchain.  Cheers!

Comment: Be sure to only move the files while the Bitcoin node is not running!